# jquery mobile delegate alert shows page name - how to remove?

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile, cordova

I have a small app, that needs to prompt calling 911 before submitting a complaint.

I am using this code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).delegate("#index", "pagebeforecreate", function() {
  alert("If this is an emergency, dial 911");
});
  </script>
```

This works, however, the app says "index.html" and the alert below it. 
How do I remove the "index.html" part?

The page uses phonegap, jquery mobile, and launching on an ios device.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Phonegap Notification API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification).